# factorizing 2 cols in my data producing different graphs

Tags: r, r-factor, mutate

I factorized 2 cols of my data, when plotted its yielding different graphs, Can anyone please guide whats wrong I'm doing?

Thanks.

Here is my data:

```
food <- data_frame(Foods = rep(c('FoodA','FoodB','FoodC','FoodD'), times = 4),
                 Stage = rep(c('E', 'L', 'P', 'A'), each = 4),
                 Mean = c(2.3, 2.1, 4.3, 3.8, 19.8, 29.0, 42.2, 29.5, 8.4, 11.9, 15.0, 12.1, 10.0, 9.1, 9.1, 11.8),
                 SD = c(0.49, 0.35, 0.70, 0.59, 1.13, 1.71, 1.72, 1.53, 0.63, 1.11, 0.74, 0.51, 0.39, 0.52, 0.37, 0.27))
```

I want to sort `Foods` col in alphabetical order, hence, I have factored `Foods` col and plotted. Graphs correctly represents as per `Mean` col.

#`Foods` col factored:

```
food <- food |> mutate(Foods = factor(Foods, labels = sort(unique(Foods))))
food |> ggplot(aes(Foods, Mean, fill = Stage)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')
```

I aslo want to stack bars in 'E', 'L', 'P', 'A' order. hence, when I factorize the col: `Stage` and plotted. But, this time graphs looks differently. 'L' data is plotted to 'P'.

```
food <- food |> mutate(Foods = factor(Foods, labels = sort(unique(Foods)))) |> mutate(Stage = factor(Stage, labels = c('E', 'L', 'P', 'A')))
food |> ggplot(aes(Foods, Mean, fill = Stage)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')
```

Here are graphs:
Graph1: [`Foods` col only factorised][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl6bY.png

Graph2: [`Foods` & `Stage` col factorised][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YADz.png

Kindy please help me, or guide me what wrong I'm doing? why data of is wrongly plotted?

Comment: Use `levels =` not `labels =`. The `labels` argument is when you want to change the labels. You got lucky with `Foods` because the default level order is alphabetical, so when you specified the labels also in alphabetical order, they lined up. But with `Stage`, the default alphabetical level order does not line up.

Comment: (And on that note, since what you want is alphabetical order for `Foods`, you can simplify to `Foods = factor(Foods)`. You only need to specify the order in `levels =` if you don't want the default alphabetical order.)